# JCrop selection on image problem in IE

Tags: asp.net, jquery

I am using JCrop to crop an image after upload with Ajax upload
control in my web application. It works great on Chrome, Firefox but
not in IE. I use JCrop v0.9.12 (build: 20130202) and IE
v10.0.9.9200.16635. Problem is JCrop selection doesn't work in IE.
Thanks!

Here is my scripts.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    jQuery(document).ready
        (function ($) {
            // To hold the API and image size.
        var jcrop_api, boundx, boundy;
            $('#<%=imgCrop.ClientID%>').Jcrop (
                {  // img_crop is the ID of image control
                    onChange: updatePreview, // will display the selected img on change.
                    onSelect: updatePreview, // will display the selected img Img_preview
                    onSelect: storeCoords, // will tell the coordinates
                    aspectRatio: 11 / 15
                }, function ()
                {
                    jcrop_api = this;
                    var bounds = this.getBounds();
                    boundx = bounds[0];
                    boundy = bounds[1];
                }
            );

        function updatePreview(c) {
            if (parseInt(c.w) > 0) {
                var rx = 100 / c.w;
                var ry = 100 / c.h;
                $('#<%=Img_preview.ClientID%>').css({  //Img_preview is the ID of image control
                    width: Math.round(rx * boundx) + 'px',
                    height: Math.round(ry * boundy) + 'px',
                    marginLeft: '-' + Math.round(rx * c.x) + 'px',
                    marginTop: '-' + Math.round(ry * c.y) + 'px'
                });
            }
        };           
    });

    // will store the selected part the images coordinates
    function storeCoords(c) {
        jQuery('#<%=W.ClientID%>').val(c.w);
        jQuery('#<%=H.ClientID%>').val(c.h);
        jQuery('#<%=X.ClientID%>').val(c.x);
        jQuery('#<%=Y.ClientID%>').val(c.y);
    };

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

A common fix for IE is to do

```
        $.Jcrop('#<%=imgCrop.ClientID%>', {  
                // your inits
        });
```